# Código alfanumérico único y no deducible Java

Tags: java, app

estoy haciendo una mini app de gestión de entradas de un campo de fútbol y tengo dos tipos de entrada, las normales y las VIP, el caso es que las entradas VIP necesitan tener un campo alfanumérico no deducible y único que actuará de contraseña para una taquilla.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Lo que necesitas es la Clase [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). Saludos

Comment: Necesito un código que se dará como una contraseña alfanumérica para una taquilla, debe ser única, ya que todas las entradas tienen un código, no pueden repetirse ni deducirse por la información de la entrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando [Apache Common Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

```
int longitud = 10;
boolean usarLetras = true;
boolean usarNumeros = true;
String idTaquilla = RandomStringUtils.random(longitud, usarLetras, usarNumeros);

System.out.println(idTaquilla);
```

Usando Java 8

```
int min = 48; // numero '0'
int max = 122; // letra 'z'
int longitud = 10;
Random random = new Random();

String idTaquilla = random.ints(min, max + 1)
  .filter(i -> (i <= 57 || i >= 65) && (i <= 90 || i >= 97))
  .limit(longitud)
  .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
  .toString();

System.out.println(idTaquilla);
```